# XML document from class path resource Config.xml is invalid

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse

I freshly started learning spring framework but while I am trying to execute helloworld project I am not able to see the output I am getting this output when I run the project please find the images below. This is the structure I have in my eclipse IDE.[image]

This is the error I am getting[image]

And this is Config.xml and Java Code I have written
package com.springtutorial;

```
public class HelloWorld {
  private String message;

  public void setMessage(String message){
     this.message=message;
  }

  public void getMessage(){
     System.out.println("Your Message:"+message);
  }
}
```

and

```
package com.springtutorial;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String []args){
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Config.xml");

        HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
        hw.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is my config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.springtutorial.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World">
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: `xmmlns` must be `xmlns` in your header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

</beans>
```

or

you can try alose this below code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

</beans>
```

Comment: Hi @Mayank Sharma the first one worked well the other one is not. Thanks any way